# Which is the best technology to make live multi-user video conference in a web application?

Tags: web-applications, video-streaming, live

My criteria are : less latency possible & less installation needed on client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is a good choice. You need to have the [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/index.html) installed on the server to use this.

There are many packages out there to [make this easier](http://www.google.com/search?q=flash+video+conferencing).

Comment: Yeah I tried with FMS but im a bit desapointed by the result with 10 users and more. Do you known anything else ?

Thanks for your anwser.